# PHP - if array data meets criteria then change before page is loaded

Tags: php

Variable `$list` stores an array like the one below.

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
       (
         [warehouse] => Array
            (
              [warehouseName] => Warehouse Europe
              [warehouseType] => en detail
            )

          [products] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => APPAREL SHIRTS
                        [productCode] => 54059761696
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => T-SHIRTS - SADAL
                        [productCode] => 54059764755
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 0
                    )


  ........... more data ............
```

Using the following piece of code I print it on the display:

```
foreach($list as $item) {
    foreach($item['products'] as $product) {
        $wName = $item['warehouse']['warehouseName'];
        $wType = $item['warehouse']['warehouseType'];
        $pr =implode(',',$product);
        printf("%s,%s,%s".PHP_EOL,$wName,$wType,$pr);
    }
}
```

How can i search if quantity is more than 3, and if it meets the criteria than change it to ">2" before the information is passed to the browser?

Basically i need to keep the quantity confidential and only show ">2" if 3 or more products are retrieved from the array.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the data coming from? anyway it should be trivial to add an if before the printf line that says `if($quantity >2){$quantity=">2";}`

Comment: btw, i don't see the quantity in your code defined anywhere... I assume you have a $quantity variable stored somewhere

Comment: @LelioFaieta it's in the array, e.g. `[quantity] => 1`

Comment: where is in the printf statement? do you see it?

Comment: No, what's your point? *i don't see the quantity in your code defined anywhere* I pointed out where it is. End of story.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca OP asks to echo one thing instead of another. I am looking for the piece of code where he is echoing that information he wants to replace...

Comment: @LelioFaieta I gather they didn't write that piece of code yet and are asking how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the quantity is more than 2 and change the value you're going to display by using a ternary operator. So inside your inner `foreach`, before printing, you can do

```
$quantity = ($product['quantity'] > 2 ? '>2' : $product['quantity']);
```

Then you can print `$quantity` wherever you want it (as long as you're still inside your inner loop).